# C# Tell static GIFs apart from animated ones

Tags: c#, image, types, gif

I'll keep it short and simple;

is there any way of telling static GIF images apart from animated ones? I'm using C#.

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Here's an article about how to determine the number of frames in a GIF animation](http://authors.aspalliance.com/brettb/ASPNETDetermineAnimatedGIFFrameCount.asp).

```
Image i = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("AnimatedGIF.gif"));

Imaging.FrameDimension FrameDimensions = 
    new Imaging.FrameDimension(i.FrameDimensionsList[0]);

int frames = i.GetFrameCount(FrameDimensions);

if (frames > 1) 
    Response.Write("Image is an animated GIF with " + frames + " frames");
else 
    Response.Write("Image is not an animated GIF.");
```

And I assume you could just compare that with 1.

Comment: +1 Hardcore article in a tiny font!  Could you paste a snippet of the code here and link to the article as well?  So that if the page or site gets deleted the answer is not lost.

Comment: @amelvin: good idea. i see jeff has already done it, now =)
@jeff atwood: props for changing the variable names to convention!

Comment: Thanks for adding the code here, the website is no longer available.

Comment: If your objective is to detect animation then answer from deadpixel is the cleaner approach.

Answer (score 6):

**System.Drawing.ImageAnimator.CanAnimate** has been available since .NET 1.1.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imageanimator.cananimate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether the specified image contains time-based frames.

Example:

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile("somefile.gif"))
{
    if (ImageAnimator.CanAnimate(image))
    {
        // GIF is animated
    }
    else
    {
        // GIF is not animated
    }
}
```